# Android Studio Cordova project doesn't have the option to generate as APK/App Bundle

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, bundle

I have inherited an Android Studio project from a previous developer that uses Cordova. This is a template that we have used for three years for each new app we build. I have very little experience with building in Android and have Googled my way through so far.

With the August 2021 update on Google Play Store I'm now needing to submit our newest app in bundle format, but I don't seem to have a way to do this.

I have seen guides referring to a 'Generate apk/bundle' option that should be visible under 'build' from the top menu, but this option is not visible for me:

[image]

Whenever I've used this template before, there was a message displayed saying "*Migrate Project to Gradle? This project does not use the Gradle build system*". My understanding from a day of research is that although my **module** had a build.gradle folder, the top level **project** also needed one (and a settings.gradle file). This seems to have worked as there is now a 'Gradle' that syncs successfully when I make a change.

When I use the command '**cordova build**', the project is building successfully.

I've also read that you can use **gradlew bundlerelease** to generate a bundle, but if I use **gradlew tasks** then there is no task available relating to bundling.

I'd really appreciate any advice on how I bundle this app please.

EDIT: By changing directory into app/platforms/android, the gradlew bundlerelease function works. I receive a BUILD SUCCESSFUL message, but nothing is actually being generated.

Comment: what versions of cordova/android studio are you using?

Comment: I've updated Android Studio to the latest version - 2020.3.1 Arctic Fox. For Cordova I'm not sure how to find out

Comment: Use the command cordova -v

Comment: Thanks. Result = 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is reading this in the future, thought I'd post my solution here.

My issue was that after manually adding the top project-level build.gradle and gradle.settings files, Android Studio converted it to be Gradle-based and somehow my existing module was not recognised. I had to create a new module inside the project, upgrade Cordova to 10.0.0 and migrate the project to Android X.

After the above changes, the menu option to generate the app bundle existed and finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to generate the bundle using

```
cordova build android --release -- --packageType=bundle
```

See https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/729 for more details

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I ran the command as suggested but unfortunately it seems to have generated an APK file instead of a .adb. This was the response: Built the following apk(s):[HIDDEN]/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk

Comment: Just to update you (or anyone else) - by changing directory into app/platforms/android the gradlew bundleRelease command worked. It printed out a "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" message, but I can't see anything that's been generated anywhere.